# How to print without a newline without using end=" "?

Tags: python, function, numbers, range, newline

I need to design a function named firstN that, given a positive integer n, displays on the screen the first n integers on the same line, separated by white space.

An example of using the function could be:

```
>>> firstN(10)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I have done this:

```
def firstN(n):
    for i in range(10):
        print (i, end=" ")
firstN(10);
```

but I can't put end=" " because my teacher has a compiler that doesn't allow it

Comment: Is your teacher using version 2 of Python?

Comment: You could assemble the entire string using `join` (or a for loop) and then print it with 1 `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. Yes, my teacher was using the version 2 of python. I have alredy solved the question.
To print without a newlineyou need to put a comma:

```
def firstN(n):
    for i in range(10):
        print (i,)
firstN(10);
```

Comment: In Python 2 you also need to remove the parentheses. `(1,)` creates a tuple, which is not at all what you want.

Comment: Please tell your teacher to update this. Even the most recent 2.x versions are as outdated as Windows 7 is, and they equally have **not been supported** for three full years now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use starred expression to unpack iterable arguments:

```
def firstN(n):
    print(*(range(n)))

firstN(10)

# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```